# Add Users to Assignee List in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

Logged in as an Administrator, I've manually added a few users to SonarQube. However, when trying to assign an issue, these users are not listed.

[image: No users listed in Assignee List]

Is there some level of permissions that need to be granted to these users to be able assign issues to them?

Answer (score 0):

This actually just seems to be the case where the documentation does not match the product. The documentation shows users in the drop-down:

[image: Image from documentation]

The actual product shows as in my question:
[image: Image from original question]

But if you type in the Search... field, you actually can find the person and make the assignment:
[image]